# Regarding boot repair

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bootrepair

I've repaired grub using boot repair disk x64. I've windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 on laptop both are working properly. I want to reinstall windows copy but it fails to boot from DVD and win 7 iso through usb. I've set the booting priority properly but it always goes to grub. So how can I install new windows?

Comment: The win 7 flash drive is the only thing hooked up via usb and is "bootable" correct? Obvious things but just double checking.

Answer (score 1):

Login into your windows, from here boot your windows DVD and run your setup. This will reinstall your Windows7 but can't alter your partition table.

Now you can update your grub using your Ubuntu live CD.

ref. [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189410/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-7-while-keeping-my-dual-boot-configuration)